# Comparing strings in java and editing

Tags: java, string

I want to compare two strings in Java.

```
String s1 = "John James Joanne Catherine Paul Steve";
String s2 = "Ian John Catherine Paul Mike Tim Ray";
```

What I am after is a third string, that has compared `s1` to `s2` and removed any matches from `s1`. So what I would be left with would be "James Joanne Steve". The strings could be in any mixed order and length.

Does any one know how this can be done?

Comment: Using Sets can be a way to achieve that.

Comment: These kind of questions are asked in interviews a lot many times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rigthy said by JB Nizet but if you want to go without using any sets or build in methods then here is the code:-

```
    String s1 = "John James Joanne Catherine Paul Steve";
    String s2 = "Ian John Catherine Paul Mike Tim Ray"; 

    String s3="";
    int checker=0;

    String[] s1_=s1.split(" ");
    String[] s2_=s2.split(" ");

    for(int i=0;i<s1_.length;i++)
    {
        for(int j=0;j<s2_.length;j++)
        {
            if(!s1_[i].equals(s2_[j]))
            {
                checker=checker+1;
            }
        }
        if(checker==s2_.length)
        {
            s3=s3+s1_[i];
        }
        checker=0;
    }

    System.out.println(s3);
```

Hope it helps .Have a good day !

Answer (score 2):

1. Split your two strings to extract the various first names.
2. Create two [`Set<String>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Set.html) to contain the first names of each original string
3. Use [`Set.removeAll()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Set.html#removeAll-java.util.Collection-) to remove all the elements of the second set from the first set.

Answer (score 0):

I would use a [StringTokenizer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/StringTokenizer.html) / [Scanner](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) with delimiters and iterate on the strings comparing the values. If a "token" of s2 is not found in s1, then I would put it in a new string (with a [StringBuilder](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html) object)

This approach would be probably slower but it costs you less memory (compared with the solution with a Set).

Comment: I see the motivation, but I see that costing O(n^2) runtime as opposed to ~O(n) if one is converting to sets.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code, this will help you,

```
String s1 = "John James Joanne Catherine Paul Steve";
String s2 = "Ian John Catherine Paul Mike Tim Ray";

Scanner inp1 = new Scanner(s1);

String output = "";

while (inp1.hasNext()) {
    String temp = inp1.next();
    int flag = 0;
    Scanner inp2 = new Scanner(s2);
    while (inp2.hasNext()) {
        if (temp.equals(inp2.next())) {//comparing one string of s1 with every string of s2
            flag = 1;
            break;
        }
    }
    inp2.close();
    if (flag == 1) {
        output += temp + " ";
    }
}
System.out.println(output);
inp1.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a [`Pattern regular expression`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) to achieve that.

Try this code :

```
String s1 = "John James Joanne Catherine Paul Steve";
String s2 = "Ian John Catherine Paul Mike Tim Ray";

//construct the regex for the s2 words
String[] wordsS2 = s2.split(" ");
String regex ="\\b(?:";

for ( String w : wordsS2)
    regex += w +"|";

regex += ")\\b\\s*";

//replace all matches with an empty string in s1
Pattern matches= Pattern.compile(regex, Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
Matcher m = matches.matcher(s1);
String s3 = m.replaceAll("");

//print the result
System.out.println(s3);
```